# How not to pointlessly rebuild dependancies during javascript developpement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, makefile, build-tools

I am not a professional developer - I'm just a self-taught amateur in the field, and I followed the trends with quite some delay. My history with javascript goes back to when I was 14 years old and randomly opened files on my `C:/Windows/` directory (it was Windows 98), until I found some intriguing `.js` files. I learned PHP, C and python, but came back to Javascript and follow his evolution from a scripting language to a full-stack tool - first, I played with Jquery a Jquery / XSLT stack, then made a little videogame using Websocket and Gulp and browserify , then recently learnt some Angular, Ionic and Vue, all based on Webpack.

I'm having though about what tool to use as a task manager. Especially, I tends to think most of the tools used these days are inefficient - hard to configure, needing a thousand plugins to work, which often create incompatibilities between versions,... And more importantly (I may be wrong here) but how come none of them are checking which dependencies need to be rebuild?

Last time, I was launching my test in a typescript project using `npm test` and got really frustrated. I realized the whole project was compiled every-time I changed a tiny detail in my test files. Having developed in C, I found that really inefficient and wrote a `makefile` to address that.

Now the bad side of `make` is that it's kinda hard to make it work with modern javascript tools (`tsc` explicitely adviced me to use a `.tsconfig` file instead of the CLI). Another example is there is no official CLI tool to compile a `.vue` file into a render() function.

Now my question is *is there a modern tool that doesn't require me to rebuild, compile, minify, uglify  my whole project and lose 30 seconds every time I add a commas in a file?* and *what's wrong with make?*

I would take any idea or correction about that matter with gratitude :)

Comment: Real it in you've gone off the deep end.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact nature of your project but I don't think there is a single tool for all the things you want to achieve. That's why we have the term "javascript fatigue".

Currently Webpack is the closest thing we have "one ring to rule them all" in terms of module management in development environments for javascript projects.

> Now my question is is there a modern tool that doesn't require me to rebuild, compile, minify, uglify my whole project and lose 30 seconds every time I add a commas in a file? and what's wrong with make?

Since you mention you are familiar with webpack, maybe you can checkout its hot module replacement feature. Here is its description straight from the developers' website:

Hot Module Replacement (HMR) exchanges, adds, or removes modules while an application is running, without a full reload. This can significantly speed up development in a few ways:

- Retain application state which is lost during a full reload.
- Save valuable development time by only updating what's changed.
- Tweak styling faster -- almost comparable to changing styles in the browser's debugger.

It is a sad fact that with each tool comes extra cognitive load. To reduce it, maybe you can:

- follow certain patterns and habits in your workflow
- have basic setups or boilerplate projects for frequent ones
- check out the best practices
- take advantage of cheat sheets and API docs
- checkout source code before searching on the internet, It maybe less time consuming and less confusing than searching on the internet
- try to master few vital tools for your projects

Following the works of developers who move the community forward maybe helpful for staying up to date with technologies, usually they gave speech and write articles.

It may look a lot of work when you see them listed one after the other but you will see it is more rewarding and less time consuming in the long run.

Please remember that, it is a common problem among developers, even the best ones suffer from it. That is why we have these tools in the first place. Good news is that, with every passing day dust is settling and tools are getting better, more mature and more stable.

For more on hot module replacement:

- https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/